# The best way to create a time converter with an enum

Tags: javascript, enums

I have some doubts for creating a time converter.
I created the class Time which can convert a time in milliseconds, seconds, minutes, hours and days. Although I did it easily, I'm not sure my code is clean. Actually, I created the enum DurationType, and each element contains the product that permits to convert it in milliseconds. That allows me to have a code of 30 lines, but it seems weird to multiply a value by DurationType.HOUR for example.

```js
"use strict";

const DurationType = {
    DAY: 24*60*60*1000,
    HOUR: 60*60*1000,
    MINUTE: 60*1000,
    SECOND:1000,
    MILLISECOND: 1
}
```

```js
    "use strict";

    class Time {
        constructor(value, type=DurationType.MILLISECOND) {
            this.setValue(value, type);
        }

        getValueIn(type=DurationType.MILLISECOND) {
            return convertTo(this.value, DurationType.MILLISECOND, type);
        }

        setValue(value, type) {
            this.value = Time.convertTo(value, type, DurationType.MILLISECOND);
        }

        static convertTo(value, type, wantedType) {
            if(!(wantedType instanceof DurationType))
                return error("wantedType isn't an instance of DurationType", 1); // display the error message and return 1
            return value*type/wantedType;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you know a better way to do it ?

Comment: The question in it's current state is more suitable for the code review stackexchange over @ https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Although this: `wantedType instanceof DurationType` - can't be right. It's probably `DurationType.hasOwnProperty( wantedType )` or `wantedType instanceof Number`. And if you really want an enum, you might want to define the properties on `DurationType` as unwritable, that's the closest you will get. Or define them as strings and store the actual value privately inside a closure.